# How to Check for Absence of a File

Tags: makefile, nmake

I am trying to use nmake to create and then test my installer and uninstaller. While creation and uninstallation can be checked out of the box I cannot figure out how to check that a file got removed after uninstall.

Thanks
HG

```
  ?: InstalledFile.txt
        Setup.exe --uninstall

    InstalledFile.txt: Installer
        Setup.exe

    Installer: Setup.exe
        InstallerAssembler.py -p=Complex.xml -t=Complex

    Setup.exe: 
        p4 sync $(VIEW)
        devenv ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`make` isn't very good at representing negative logic.

The standard workaround, I believe, is to create a dummy file:

```
InstalledFile.txt.isabsent:
    (some command that creates the target if InstalledFile.txt does not exist, and fails otherwise)
```

Comment: Yes, looks like the only way out is to use auxillary utils.